# I don't understand the pattern of CheckBox click with the new parameter

Tags: java, android, listener, oncheckedchanged

The following code is used to toggle the `CheckBox` in order to make the user able to see his password :

```
passwordCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if (!isChecked) {
            passwordEditText.setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            passwordConfirmEditText.setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        } else {
            passwordEditText.setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
            passwordConfirmEditText.setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is what I understand from above: there's a CheckBox named passwordCheckBox, I'd set a listener to the CheckBox as soon as I click on it in order to (un)Toggle the CheckBox, if it's not Checked, passwordEditText won't appear as characters, if it's Checked password will appear as characters. If I am mistaken in what I assume, correct me please.

I don't understand the pattern of this code, How can the parameter "`isChecked`" which should be a new variable(?), be understood by the application where the `isChecked` is equal to "True" (And at the same time it's understood as it's the user input)

Comment: `isChecked` is an argument which will be provided by OS when check listener is fired, is it any clearer?

Comment: Could you provide me with a link with source(or explanation) so i could understand any better?

Comment: Im not sure im following your question. is its the construct `!isChecked` that you don't understand? its just a short form of `isChecked != true`

Comment: What i don't understand is this, i.e: 

private void example(int a, int b)
{
// TODO
}

a, and b are both variables inside the parameters, then how could i use it to know what was the user inputs?

similarly, isChecked is the same as (In this case) a, and b so i can't check how did the user toggle the CheckBox or not, so how could i use it in this code and it worked just fine? 

That's why i am asking for explanation about the pattern of isChecked as variable in parameter

Comment: sorry I still dont undertand :) when user interacts with check box (ui element) Android (an OS) will call your code back with the currect state of the check box, argument `isChecked` is set to current state and passed to you

Comment: Link with source, lines 153, 156: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/CompoundButton.java#CompoundButton.setChecked%28boolean%29.

Comment: @hellohello That construct is called an anonymous class. OnCheckedChanged is not called by your code, it's called by Android internal code only when the user interacts with the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone, i now understand more, i'll look into the code that was linked above to understand even more. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer:
@hellohello That construct is called an anonymous class. OnCheckedChanged is not called by your code, it's called by Android internal code only when the user interacts with the checkbox.  – Christian Strempfer

All thanks for other comments